# NPM question: Didn't run NPM Install, project runs, install, project fails on several points

Tags: angular, git, npm

I've inherited a project, and the machine previous dev was working on, everything seems to be working fine, Then comes to do a new UAT, so I do the standard, install everything, project is failing, Angular8? might be the problem, I'm all over several sites/forums about changes, @NewChild needing 2 parameters, typescript can't be above 3.5 etc, I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I look at the copy I have on a working dev machine.. everything 'seems' legit.. So I blank out my UAT machine, start again, but for what ever reason, frustration I guess, I installed core and cli, but I skipped the 'npm install' phase after that, and it all works.

I go over whats happening on the dev machine, and seems that it too never had npm install run.

How does this even work? Why would npm install break things? I had maybe 7 or 8 packages fail, node_modules is not in the git repo, and I wiped that folder thrice, so it can't be an old copy of files.

Heres the working package.

```
 {
    "name": "fail-app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.5",
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.0",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "^6.3.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.3.3",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.30",
        "@types/fullcalendar": "^3.8.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "angular-2-daterangepicker": "^1.1.48",
        "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^2.2.1",
        "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.2.1",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
        "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.1",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
        "angular5-csv": "^0.2.10",
        "angular5-time-picker": "^1.0.8",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "bootstrap-menu": "^1.0.14",
        "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "^3.6.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery-timepicker": "^1.3.3",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.6.2",
        "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.12",
        "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.6",
        "ng-select": "^1.0.0",
        "ng2-smart-table": "^1.3.5",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
        "ngx-contextmenu": "^5.0.1",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
        "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
        "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
        "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
        "open-iconic": "^1.1.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
        "timepicker": "^1.11.12",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "ts-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "^2.7.2"
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Visual Studio will also install packages on load when there is a `packages.json` file.

Comment: @Zze, Interesting, I would presume only certain packages, since when I run `npm install` many things break?

Comment: It may happen because your packages are not compatible with angular version, for example `angular-2-daterangepicker` supports angular v4, v5 as per [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-daterangepicker)

Comment: @Anna, while that may be true for just the one module, I had several fail, so I don't think its a specific package. The main point is.. If they're 'in' node_modules, but not installed, what does 'npm install' do that's causing a break.. a question for NPM geniuses maybe?

Comment: It'll be good if you try to share some errors.

Comment: @Anna, there are over 30 (I've pointed out a few in the post), and when I traced them, they're all related to being, or not being up to date, when I changed all the code to get them all working, nothing worked, I'm sure, if I had the time, I could find all the faults and fix, but as per usual, no time, just find the fix.. which for now = Don't run `npm install`. The question is "why" does it work, when nothing is installed.

Comment: Your may have the older packages installed at level up(from your project) or globally, so they are picked from there and all works